# The number of integral solutions $(x,y)$ of $x^3+3x^2y+3xy^2+2y^3=50653$

Tags: number-theory, contest-math, diophantine-equations

This was a wonderful question given to me by professor in my last class test. He asked for the solution with the least number of steps.

> Find the number of integral solutions $(x,y)$ of the equation:
>
> $$x^3+3x^2y+3xy^2+2y^3=50653$$

Can anyone do it?

Comment: and $50653=37^3$.

Comment: @mathlove Wasn't it a nice and subtle one?

Comment: Reminds me on "how many integer solutions has $x^3+y^3+z^3=3$ ?" So far we have $4$ solutions, $(1,1,1)$ and $(4,4,-5)$ with permutations.

Comment: @DietrichBurde this question is just FLT

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that this is
$$
(x + y)^3 + y^3 = 37^3;
$$
by Wiles' theorem the only integral solutions are $(37,0)$ and $(-37,37)$.

Comment: @Dhruv, I interpreted this as meaning the "shortest" solution; this one uses essentially two steps, rewriting the equation and applying one theorem (be it a cannon). Perhaps there is a notion of "step" that I don't understand?

Comment: That is not Wiles' theorem.  Euler or the unattributed "Fermat's last theorem for $n=3$" would be correct.